# retrieve json encoded multidimensional array with ajax

Tags: php, arrays, json, ajax

I successfully (tested) call an ajax request to a php script. This is the portion of code i need to make working:

```
   success: function (response, status) {
       $.each(response, function (i, item) {
          alert(item.id);
```

item.id is just...nothing.

This is the generated - json_encoded array by php page:

```
[
  {
    "conto": "1"
  },
  {
    "id": "4",
    "activity_id": "50",
    "path": "Testo/base.png",
    "title": "Ffgf",
    "descrizione": "Tttt"
  },
  {
    "id": "8",
    "activity_id": "50",
    "path": "Testo/61FCFUX_IMG_0536.PNG",
    "title": "Hggggg",
    "descrizione": "Tgg"
  }
]
```

What do I do wrong?

p.s: if you noticed, this is an array merge between two arrays: the first one just reports "conto" in in, the other one is a list generated by fetching elements by database.

Comment: In the first iteration, `item.id` won't be defined, since it simply doesn't exist in that object. Check with: `if (item.id) { //do your stuff }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first array not containing id so you are getting undefined value. Skip first array:

```
$.each(response, function (i, item) {
         if(i==0)
         {
            alert(item.costo);
          }
          else
          {
            alert(item.id);
           //Or better to use console
           console.log(item.id);
          }

        });
```

Comment: Not working...the problem i think it's related to the fact it's a multidimensional array.

Comment: Then check your response because as per your example it should work.. See example: https://jsfiddle.net/sqdjk1zL/

Comment: @GiovanniPalerma Where is the multidimensional array you are talking about?

Comment: but in this way seems like i can't retrieve item.conto anymore. Basically i need to access the first array as a condition. i have "if (item.conto !=1) do something". @Coder my mistake, it's not a multidimensional array.

if (item.conto!=1) { if (i>0) { ...?

Comment: mmm still not what i mean. conto could be 1 or another number. i need to execute a code only if conto !=1 basically my actual code look like this:http://pastebin.com/ia24un1Q

Answer (score -1):

I believe your issue is with your reference.  Since your JSON object contains an array you will need to reference it with subscripts.  Try changing item.id to item[i].id.  That way as the each function iterates through the array, it can reference the id field in each object.

Edit: Here's working code.

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    var source = '[{"conto":"1"},{"id":"4","activity_id":"50","path":"Testo\/base.png","title":"Ffgf","descrizione":"Tttt"},{"id":"8","activity_id":"50","path":"Testo\/61FCFUX_IMG_0536.PNG","title":"Hggggg","descrizione":"Tgg"}]';
    source = JSON.parse(source);
    var cellcount = length(source);

    for(var i = 0; i < cellcount; i++){
        console.log(source[i].id);
    }

});

function length(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length;
}
```

Comment: The OP is using jQuery's `.each()` so `item` will be the actual object. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/. Even if that wasn't the case, it's `item[i]` (array/object index) , not `item(i)` (function call).

Comment: @MagnusEriksson As you will see from the edited answer, I added code that shows what I was talking about.  I just needed a minute to get it all straight before fixing it.  Don't be so quick to downvote people.

Comment: @Daniel Don't be worried about the downvotes. They just try to suggest so that you will improvise.

Comment: If you post an answer that's all wrong and doesn't take into account what the OP is actually doing, it will get downvoted. That's how this site works. What you should do is write a proper answer before hitting the "save" button. We have no idea if you're planing to expand on it or not later.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  Maybe wait more than a couple minutes past when it's posted.  Most people do edit their answers. All you did was jump at the downvote and provide no answer.  Is that what you mean by "how this site works"?  And you were wrong,  I posted an answer that was on topic and correct except for a syntax error.  Gimme a break, I work with a dozen languages every day.